# Creating multiple message loops for nested controls of a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Very long story short, I have a need to place a WinForms Panel and an instance of an unmanaged class that draws on it in a separate thread to keep the main window responsive (the SDK can sometimes take several seconds to come up with what it will draw, and while it is doing this it blocks the UI thread). I actually need many of these (up to 32), but we'll talk about just one for now; the concept should be able to be duplicated as many times as necessary.

What I think I need to do is start a new Thread that will "new up" a Panel, then start an ApplicationContext that isn't tied to anything in particular, and assign it to the Panel. Then, the Panel class should have a Dispose() overload that will end the ApplicationContext, shutting down the message pump and terminating the thread.

What I need to know is:

- Can the Panel be placed inside an IContainer, or added to the Controls collection of any parent object? Or, will doing this cause non-thread-safe calls to be made?
- I have a static factory method on the class that creates new instances on new threads. I need to return a reference to that Panel (created in the background thread) from the method so I can work with it. Is there a better way to do so than to wait in a while/sleep loop for a variable defined locally in the static method to be set by the background thread?
- Do I need to keep a reference to the Thread that owns the Panel?
- Am I insane for trying this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't approach the problem this way.  You should have the drawing threads draw to in-memory images, and have the UI thread render those images to the panel.  If the drawing threads produce a new image for each iteration, then the UI thread can cache the image and replace it each time a new one becomes available.  You'll save yourself a lot of headaches later on, rather than trying to usurp the expected threading behavior.

Comment: +1: This is called "offscreen compositing".  It is used by most applications that take a while to load images while having the need to keep the UI responsive and flicker free.  This includes everything from game engines to browsers.

Comment: Good idea; however, I don't think I have that luxury. The SDK expects an HWnd to draw on, so I'm pretty sure I have to give it a GUI element known to Windows.